# Subversion Edge SVN two instance on CentOs

Tags: svn, centos, instances, subversion-edge

I have installed and configured `Subversion Edge 3.3.2 (Linux 64-bit)` on `CentOs ( 64-bit )`.
And its working good.

And I have two doubts

1. Can we create two instances of SVN on same server
2. I did started working on creating two instances on machine, and i created with different directory name as `anotherCSVN`
   and it shows the server is started with

`http://localhost:3343/csvn`

And this is the same url for previous SVN instance.. and i was expecting something about (I dont know why, even i know little about apache http mod )

`http://localhost:3343/anotehrCSVN`

There might be any changes, do we need to in apache configuration at previous or current `SVN` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, but it is a very manual process.  The name of the folder where you install Subversion Edge has nothing to do with the URL it is access.  The URL will always be /csvn.  What you can do is manually override the port numbers being used so that they are unique and you can have a second instance.  There is documentation in a wiki page on how to do this:

https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/ModifyPorts

Once the web console is started, you would of course also need to configure the Apache server in this second instance to be using a unique port that does not clash with the other instance.

If you want to "install" init.d scripts to autostart both instances, then you also need to rename those scripts so that they do not clash.  The default scripts are in the bin folder and named "csvn" and "csvn-httpd".